# Copy/Paste Date using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert the date using the Today Function in Excel. I have a sheet with the date at the top, in Cell I2.

I have a table and am using VBA to copy paste values into it - this will be used daily and I want the date to be auto populated into Column D, starting from the last used row in Column D and ending with the last used row in Column C. I then want the date to be saved as value.

I tried using the following code but it didn't work - nothing happened.

Can someone please help me understand why, and how to correct this?

```
With ThisWorkbook
    With .Sheets("Test")
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1))
        
        rng.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("I2").Value
    End With
End With
```

Comment: write `Debug.Print rng.Address` on the line after `Set rng = .Range`... What do you get?

Comment: That range def looks wrong. What value are you trying to get there? Say the last used row is 5. Do you want the range to be C5:D5? In this case, you will only get D5

Comment: Can you explain (in words) what do you want accomplishing? `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)` refers to D:D range, too. But counting C:C last row.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

1. Find the last used row with `Column C` (*Assumes the last row in C & D are equal so just calculate this in one column. It looks like you are trying to over-complicate*)
2. Skip the temp `rng` assignment and apply the value transfer using a combination of `Offset` when calculating `lr` and `Resize` when referencing the target row

---

```
Sub Try_Me()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")
Dim lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
ws.Range("C" & lr).Resize(1, 2).Value = ws.Range("I2").Value

End Sub
```

---

Looking at your current `Set rng = ...` statement it looks like you ***may*** be trying to determine the last used row in either column indicating that the last used row in both may vary. If that is the case, you can compare both and pick the max like so:

```
Sub Try_Me()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim c As Long, d As Long, lr As Long

c = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
d = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(c, d)
ws.Range("C" & lr).Resize(1, 2).Value = ws.Range("I2").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: So this works in terms of inserting the formula. I think I need to explain a bit more - lets say Columns C and D end at the same row, for example Row 3, I then use an old already existing macro to insert values into column C so that the last used row is now Row 10. I want to create a new macro that will insert a specific formula into Column D from the previously used row until the last used row, so from Row 3 to Row 10 will be this formula. Does that make sense?